# "The best part of it" vs "Its best part"

Tags: phrase-choice

Let's makeup a movie named "XYZ". Let's say a friend of mine said, "I watched a movie named "XYZ" last night. It was really good. Did you watch it before?". I answered, "Yes, I did"; and he asked, "What do you think about it?". As an answer to this question, can I say these interchangeably? Would they have the same exact meaning?

- "I think it is a good movie. John's death was **its best part**."
- "I think it is a good movie. John's death was **the best part of it**."

What I mean is that the death of the character named John was the best part of the movie.

Comment: Yes, they are interchangeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Both of your options have the same meaning here. You could even just say,

> I think it is a good movie. John's death was the best part.

The "of it" part of your second bullet is implied in my option above.